# Centered div and fluid left padding over the container

Tags: css, fluid-layout

I have a centered red div (blue) with a max width (1240px) in my layout and I search to make this in CSS. The logo area (purple) from the left of the centering area (blue) is 300px. At the left of this point, in red, it will be fluid (whatever the screen resolution you have).

(btw, that's the same thing for the lightgray div just below)

Do you have an idea to do that?

[image]

```
<header>
   <div id="logo">
      <div class="w">
         <a href="#">Website name</a>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="wrap">
      <div class="r">
         <nav id="menu">
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            </ul>
         </nav>
         <nav id="social">
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            </ul>
         </nav>
      </div>
   </div>
</header>
```

Comment: in the fluid part 'll you put any html in it or you just want if the resolution is big to be just empty?

Comment: it will be red, like the image. that's a extension of the logo background (which is red too) / so, just a background color

Comment: You need to place some code.

Comment: Please don't repost questions, it just makes things messy for everyone involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with a `:before` pseudo-class on the `#logo` element.

```
#logo:before{content:""; position:absolute; top:0; right:100%; width:1000%; height:100%; background:red;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Flayks/fUf2z/

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are after other than something that depends on the window size or resolution, so, does using percentages help here? You might know this allright but you can use percentages in css, in margins and paddings and widths and so on. This is directly dependent on the window size or resolution and scales?

http://mattsnider.com/css-using-percent-for-margin-and-padding/